# Client IP on Traefik with Docker Swarm

Tags: traefik

I try to get the client IP on a Traefik container which running on my Docker Swarm cluster.

On my Traefik service configuration, I use the long syntax for port publishing:

```
--publish published=80,target=80,mode=host \
--publish published=443,target=443,mode=host \
```

but on Traefik access log, I always obtain the IP address of docker_gwbridge interface.

Does any one know how to get the client IP in place of the IP of this interface?

Thanks in advance.